# Visualize graph algorithms (step-by-step) with data binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, binding, graph, visualization

I'm developing an WPF application that models the graph algorithms. I use `ListBox` with `DataTemplate`s to display the graph by binding it to an `ObservableCollection` of `Node`s and `Edge`s. At this stage, everything is displayed correctly but the algorithm cannot run step-by-step! I have searched and tried many, from `BackgroundWorker` to `Dispatcher`, but nothing worked!

*So, how can I make the algorithm displayed step-by-step? Is it possible to do with data-binding? Or must I choose another way to render the graph?*

In WinForm, there is `Sleep()` to stop on each `Node` for an amount of time and do some rendering tasks, then move on. But I think that solution only works if the algorithm and rendering task are mixed together.